# i am confused in indexing of arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Following selection sort code is generating problem in a[p]>a[j] line why?Although if i put a[i] instead of a[p] it works fine

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    p=i;
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
        if(a[p] > a[j]) {          
            p=j;  
            t=a[i];
            a[i]=a[p];
            a[p]=t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem? Please show a [mcve] and add the proper description of the issue.

Comment: *"if I put a[i] instead of a[p] it works fine"* well `p` and `i` have completely different values in your program, I don't really know what you would expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `p=j;` in the inner loop changes `p`. This causes `p` to be different from `i` later, when `if(a[p]>a[j])` is evaluated with a new `j`.

Your code does not need `p` at all. The test can be merely `if (a[i] > a[j])`, and the code inside the loop can be:

```
t = a[i];
a[i] = a[j];
a[j] = t;
```

Looking at your code, it seems you think you needed to record `i` or `j` in `p` temporarily and then use `p`. That is not necessary. To use the values of `i` or `j`, simply use `i` or `j`.